# How to load only select files in power BI desktop

Tags: powerbi, azure-blob-storage, parquet, powerbi-desktop, azure-data-lake

Power BI Desktop has support for loading single parquet file from ADLS,
[image]

Right now our process will dump multiple parquet files into a folder. The folder will have sub folders with files of other format like json or crc

My issue is I want to give folder as input and only load the parquet files.

If I try with the connector for ADLS Gen 2,
[image]

it loads the json and crc files too in the subfolder,
[image]

How can I selectively ignore and only load `.parquet` files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter based on Extension in Power Query

```
let
    Source = Folder.Files("Location"),
    FilteredData = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".parquet"))
in
    FilteredData
```

Comment: Thanks Sai! I used the query and it was able to filter only the parquet files. But the content is still metadata. i.e. table has columns on the file name, the date created, accessed etc. It doesn't actually merge the contents of all parquet files. Whereas if I use a single parquet as source, the contents within that file are shown. Perhaps the use case is not supported?

Comment: all your content will be in content column, If you are interested in data only then
Right Click on Content and click remove other columns , next expand Content column